# Taking every n-th element of one array and putting it into another array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an `array` like this:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(11) "12323423423" [1]=> string(4) "tito" [2]=> string(6) "235345" [3]=> string(14) " 564534534534" [4]=> string(5) "kralj" [5]=> string(6) "435345" }
```

Depending on number of elements from another array called `$anotherArray`, let's say `$anotherArray` has 3 elements, I should take first 3 elements of first array, then if there are second 3 elements and so on, and put them into another array. I tried it like so:

```
$lengthManuelni=count($string);// $string being array displayed uphere
$lengthAnothera=count($anotherArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthManuelni; $i += $lengthAnothera) { 
    for ($j = 0; $j < $lengthAnothera; $j++) {
        $restructured [$j] = $string[$i + $j];
        var_dump($restructured);
    }
    }
```

So i would like this `$restructured` array to look like this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(23) "12323423423,tito,235345" [1]=> string(28) " 564534534534,kralj,435345" }
```

Instead it when I do `var_dump($restructured)` it looks like this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "12323423423" } array(2) { [0]=> string(11) "12323423423" [1]=> string(4) "tito" } array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "12323423423" [1]=> string(4) "tito" [2]=> string(6) "235345" } array(3) { [0]=> string(14) " 564534534534" [1]=> string(4) "tito" [2]=> string(6) "235345" } array(3) { [0]=> string(14) " 564534534534" [1]=> string(5) "kralj" [2]=> string(6) "235345" } array(3) { [0]=> string(14) " 564534534534" [1]=> string(5) "kralj" [2]=> string(6) "435345" }
```

Please help, I'm stuck with this.

Comment: can you please post your complete input array.

Comment: Well, complete input array will vary, thats why I need to find dynamic solution, and thats why I posted this example array. I mean, complete input array may look just like $string

Comment: So you need to split the array like you show?? is all your sub array size is fixed?? I mean 6?

Comment: Thats right. Please be more specific about staff that may be unclear to you, if there is something left unexplained.

Comment: did you try `array_chunk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler to achieve this using `array_chunk` and `array_map` functions:

```
$restructured = array_map(function($v){
    return implode(",", $v);
}, array_chunk($lengthManuelni, 3));

print_r($restructured);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12323423423,tito,235345
    [1] => 564534534534,kralj,435345
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: This is exactly what i am saying for.

Comment: using array_column() as an alternative to array_map() is even easier

Comment: @MarkBaker, interesting, can you show an example using `array_column` for such case ?